# How to insert numeral into regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to insert a numeral between 2 regex groups; however, I can't figure out how to avoid referring to a different group number.

I'm attempting to use regex to update filenames in a directory. Essentially I have a season of a TV show, and all the filenames should follow the pattern "Show - S##E## - Episode Title"

I've written a simple loop to iterate over the files and set up the naming, but the issue I'm running into is that the episode number isn't set up as 2 digits in every file. I've included the loop I tried to use to fix this problem below.

I've tried to use re.sub() to identify the S##E as group 1, and the following digits as group 2, and then insert a '0' between the two groups, but I end up referencing group 10, which isn't defined. I'm not sure how to escape the group reference without referring to group 0 or inserting a backslash.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) if os.path.isfile(f)]
for file in files:
    os.rename(file, re.sub(r'(S\d+E)(\d\s)',r'\10\2',file))
```

OR

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) if os.path.isfile(f)]
for file in files:
    os.rename(file, re.sub(r'(S\d+E)(\d\s),r'\1'+'0'+r'\2', file))
```

Intended results should be for all files to follow the S##E## pattern, even for episode numbers lower than 10. The first version results in an error as I am referring to a group that doesn't exist. The second does not appear to alter the filenames at all.

Comment: Can you provide an (simplified) expected input and output?

Comment: I am iterating over an array of files. Each file begins with "Episode #" I'm trying to convert that to "Show - S##E##" and ensure that I use 2 digits to identify the season and episode in that pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a note about this in the [docs for `re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'.

So, write the group reference out in the more verbose way, so it's unambiguous:

```
os.rename(file, re.sub(r'(S\d+E)(\d\s)',r'\g<1>0\g<2>',file))
```

Comment: I read this page earlier today... Sorry for asking a question I should have known the answer to. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Happens to everyone. I actually went diving into the python source before I thought to check the docs myself :P